# onServicesDiscovered gives 'Method does not override method from its super class' Error

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

[image]I am working on Bluetooth Low energy, i have connected my Bluetooth device to my android but when i try to discover its services and implement onServicesDiscovered by Overriding it. It gives me syntax error that Method does not override method from its super class. I searched it on google and Stack but could't find any appropriate Solution. Please help me in this. 
Thanking in anticipation.
Here is my code and Screenshot of the Error.

```
@Override
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

    List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
    Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", services.toString());
    gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get
            (0));
}
```

Comment: show the whole class code. you may strip methods body but include class. also what is `syntax error` exactly? make screenshot perhaps?

Comment: i just edited my Question.

Comment: and the `class XXX extends ....`  or instantiation of the object this method belongs to?

Comment: I have written this method in my class and here is the class header.
public class A1 extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

the whole code is too long to post

Answer (score 1):

> I have written this method in my class and here is the class header. public class A1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

This is wrong. `onServicesDiscovered()` is method of abstract [BluetoothGattCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html) class. So your `@Override` tells compiler this method overrides parent's method, but you are not extending `BluetoothGattCallback` so this raises the error.

You are most victim of crappy tutorials where author didn't care isolating elements and he i.e. made Activity implementing all the interfaces and listeners, instead of having them separated. As solution you must either rework your code and extend `BluetoothGattCallback` or abandon bad practice and separate the callback i.e. by creating inner class:

```
class MyCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {
   // your code here
}
```

and then using instance of `MyCallback`.

Comment: Thank you. Its solved. but its not being invoked after services discovery!

Comment: Ok, but do you attach your callback? or you just created the class?

Comment: i have attached the call back in Inner class

Comment: ok, but this then looks like other problem. So you should [accept this answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and then open another question about your callback being not called. Do not for forget to include code that creates and attaches your callbacks in that question.